# Nutch 2.x "ant eclipse" build failed

Tags: apache, nutch

Error getting http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ant-eclipse/ant-eclipse/1.0/ant-eclipse-1.0.bin.tar.bz2

924: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded ant-eclipse-1.0.bin.tar.bz2 from the mentioned url.
I changed the line (924) in build.xml from

```
<get src="http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/ant-eclipse/ant-eclipse/1.0/ant-eclipse-1.0.bin.tar.bz2" 
dest="${build.dir}/ant-eclipse-1.0.bin.tar.bz2" usetimestamp="false" />
```

to

```
<copy file="/path/to/local/copy/of/ant-eclipse-1.0.bin.tar.bz2" 
todir="${build.dir}"/>
```